# Interpretation of this beta value

Tags: r, regression, percentage

I have a dependent variable 'Y' which is measured in percentages between 0 and 100. I also have an independent variable 'X' which is measured in whole numbers from 0 to 2000 (SD = 330).

R gives me a beta value of .0868 for the slope of X predicting Y.
I would like to describe what happens to Y when X increases. As far as I remember, beta values work with SD as units, right? So an increase in 1 unit in X (SD = 330) would mean an increase of... what in my dependent variable Y?
Does the percentage go up by 0.0868% for each increase of 330 on the x-axis, or does it increase by 8.68%?
In other words: Do I have to multiply the beta value by 100 for some reason (because percentage), or is the increase really only 0.0868% for each SD increase on X?
Or do I also have to look at the SD in the Y variable?

Thank you in advance for your help, much appreciated!

Edit: I wasn't aware that there was a sister site! I surely can provide you with my R-code: The third line is the one providing the beta weight (or pearson correlation coefficient).

```
Dichtheid_Ingeschrevenen_totaal_x_Groepsgrootte_02_mean <-
    ggpubr::ggscatter(
      Main, x = "Ingeschrevenen_totaal",
      y = "Groepsgrootte_02_mean",
      xlab="Totaal aantal studenten per opleiding", 
      ylab="Groepsgrootte bij hoorcolleges (NSE)",
      add = "reg.line",
      add.params = list(color = "blue", fill = "darkblue"),
      conf.int = TRUE) + 
    stat_cor(p.accuracy=0.001,
             r.accuracy=0.001,
             method = "pearson",
             label.x = 2000,
             label.y = 1) +
    geom_point() + 
    geom_density_2d() + 
    stat_density_2d(aes(fill = ..level..),
      geom="polygon",
      show.legend=FALSE) + 
    scale_fill_gradient(low="blue", high="red")
```

Comment: For every increase in X by 1 unit, y increases by 8.68%.

Comment: @Edward could you expand why? From my understanding, $y = a + bx$ where $y$ and $x$ are continuous variables, the interpretation of $b$ was unit increase in $y$ due 1 unit increase in $x$. When the regression is $log(y) = a + bx$, then the interpretation can be that a unit increase in $x$ leads to $100b$ % increase in $y$. I don't think the latter is the case in OP's question.

Comment: @FightMilk Let me rephrase. "Y increases by 0.0868 _percentage points_". OP did not mention log-linear regression. But the units of y is a %.